# Detect screen capture in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to detect screen capture or recording is processing.

Atleast a way to know the process behind screen capturing?

i guess something has to be done with `Kernal side of the system` but not sure.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Writing your own video driver to protect the video RAM isn't practical.  Especially not from vb.net.  Nothing stops anybody from making a photo of the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at using something like [Deviare](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/).  I haven't used it personally, but it does let you hook some of the win32 APIs including GDI32, which is probably what you would have to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture a [print scrn] button press from the keyboard, but there are so many different ways to record video and capture screens, you couldn't possibly create a solution to scan all the different types of applications that can capture this information.